# Uniting two separate ways to view questions

Tags: feature-request, tag-watching

When I come to https://stackoverflow.com/, I see "interesting" tab. However, if I click on Questions, there's no "interesting" tab there. So, there's two completely separate views on questions - one under "Questions" and one under root URL with `?tab=`. Maybe it would be better to unite them?

Comment: You find some info http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/stack-overflow-homepage-changes/. There you learn that interessting doesn#T mean filtered by your tags. From look of webdesign I find it a fault, that there is no internal navigation back to the homepage.

Comment: @bernd_k Click on the site logo to return to the homepage.

Comment: I understand that, but it's very unobvious that Questions doesn't show all ways to view questions and there's totally separate ways under the logo. It would be nicer if all ways of seeing questions were under Questions.